# Where can I find specific examples of parameters for a loudspeaker circuit model?

Tags: speakers

When I look around for loudspeaker literature, I often encounter an equivalent electrical circuit model such as http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Acoustics/Acoustic_Loudspeaker#Modeling_the_loudspeaker_as_a_lumped_system (image shown from the linked site):

[image: loudspeaker equivalent electrical circuit model]

Where can I find examples of component parameters (\$R_\mathrm{e}\$, \$L_\mathrm{e}\$, \$R_\mathrm{evc}\$ etc.) for such a model for actual loudspeakers? It does not matter which speaker it is. I just need a realistic model.

It does not have to be this exact circuit. I have also seen other variations of it and something reasonably similar will be OK.

Comment: Out of the +120 circuits I looked through in the "Audio" category on that site, none seemed to be a loudspeaker equivalent electric circuit. Can you point me to a specific circuit if you know one?

Comment: I have added the figure I refer to as an example of the circuit - I am looking for real-life examples of the component values shown in the circuit.

Answer (score 5):

[Here](https://sound-au.com/tsp.htm) is a really decent article on the subject. It incorporates the following equivalent circuit:

[image]

The article was written by Rod Elliott of Elliott Sound Products

Answer (score 1):

It seems I can find several of the parameters for a very large range of speaker drivers here http://www.thielesmall.com/ (also http://www.41hz.com/forums/content.php?253-TSdb).