# Impedance of headphones

Tags: impedance

This is probably the best [article](http://nwavguy.blogspot.com/2011/02/headphone-amp-impedance.html) for a beginner about impedance with respect to headphones.

I haven't managed to find an explanation of why the impedance of headphones is just a single, real number (like 250 Ohm). I thought impedance is a complex number, so it should have real (resistance) and imaginary (reactance) part. Maybe the imaginary part is just zero. All I know is that impedance varies with frequency.

Comment: Try this: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/83829/where-can-i-find-specific-examples-of-parameters-for-a-loudspeaker-circuit-model and note that speaker impedance is normally dominated by the winding resistance of the coil.

Comment: I've seen a Behringer musical bass amp where the "headphone" jack was wired directly to the speaker output. That certainly is under 2Ω!

Answer (score 2):

Impedance does vary by frequency. However, for many things it doesn't vary very much by frequency within the expected operating frequency of the equipment, and a single number is much easier to handle than a frequency response graph. So people quote a single average number.

In fact, your linked article admits this:

> Headphone impedance can vary by a factor of 10 or more over the audio band. The SuperFi 5 is rated at 21 ohms but varies from 10 ohms to 90 ohms.

That's quite a lot of variation! It also explains why this causes variation in the audio quality when driven from different sources.

Comment: Ok, impedance varies with frequency, that's why it's usually specified as a single number at given frequency. My other question was why it's a single real number instead of a complex number (we know impedance is a complex number).