# Wy are speakers rated by impedance instead of inductance?

Tags: audio, ac, impedance, inductance

Audio speakers contain coils which product sound by vibrating a cone.  Why are speakers rated by impedance instead of inductance?

Comment: The speaker is a motor. Air causes resistance (mechanical load). So the impedance is not purely inductive. If you are really interested, you should get your hands on a speaker and measure the complex impedance at a variety of frequencies.

Answer (score 4):

Because as shown [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/83829/11683), the inductance is not the dominant feature of the electrical model of a speaker. The electrical resistance and the mechanical resistance dominate.