# How to read AC power dissipation in LTSpice components?

Tags: ltspice

I'm interested in determining the dissipated power in an audio speaker using LTSpice.  Clearly the speaker is simply modelled as a resistance, say 8 Ohms.  LTSpice can directly display the DC power dissipation in a component, but how do I see the AC power dissipation?  Is some sort of manual calculation required or can the software provide it?

Comment: Clearly, modeling a speaker as a resistance is far from any real world speaker. [Have a look here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/83829/where-can-i-find-specific-examples-of-parameters-for-a-loudspeaker-circuit-model)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're referring to what the status bar displays when hovering over an element, or what an .`op` label might show, those are readings from `t=0`, the very beginning of the simulation, where the operation point is calculated. Even for DC circuits it may change due to transients in charging capacitors, etc.

LTspice provides a way to display the power dissipated in any element by pressing `ALT` and then `RightClick` on it. This will plot the instantaneous value, which can then be further calculated with `CTRL+Click` on the waveform's title (in the waveform viewer).

Of course, for more math, one can always add external circutry that calculates this automatically. For example, you could make use of [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/254602/how-to-integrate-a-signal-in-ltspice/254772#254772) example on how to average the AC power over a cycle, thus displaying a quasi-instantaneous average dissipated power (with a cycle delay).