# Confirmation of correct voltage and frequency to send to a speaker for it to output sound

Tags: speakers

If I have an 8 ohm speaker that's rated for 40W (assumed RMS) with a frequency range of 73 Hz to 2500 Hz, and assuming the 8 ohm impedance is the same across the entire frequency range,

does that mean I can plug in a sine wave with a frequency set somewhere from 73 Hz to 2500 Hz, and as long as the voltage supplied to the speaker measures up to ~25Vpeak from an oscilloscope, the speaker can be expected to output sound?

The 25Vpeak estimate comes from P = I^2 x R, and V = IR, so,

- I = square-root {40W RMS/ 8ohms} = 2.24A RMS
- V = 2.24A x 8 ohms = 17.89V RMS (or 25.30Vpeak)

(**Note:** *This question was asked with reference to [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/390398/40812),
but would like some additional confirmation.*)

[image]

Comment: The rated power is the maximum, so you want to always apply less power (usually much less).

Comment: Most of that input power ends up as heat, and I doubt the voice coil can dissipate 40 W indefineitely. Speakers are usually intended to play music, where most of the time the output is well below the peak.

Comment: Believe your ears rather than the label! When it starts to distort - back off.

Comment: 40W also produces a *lot* more sound than you probably think it does.

Comment: An enclosure designed for the specs of the speaker is very important to limit destruction of a speaker. Also, look at the datasheet of any speaker to see that it is about 8 ohms only at about 400Hz because it has a resonance of about 40 ohms or more at a low frequency and a rise of impedance at higher frequencies due to its inductance. Some manufacturers say a peak or maximum power rating that is actually only half of real power. Maybe their rating is only for momentary pulses and not for continuous power.

Comment: Careful not to hurt your ears! If I were you, I'd start with a really small voltage and increase it gradually.

Comment: @TannerSwett Thanks. The purpose of the question is just to find the maximum limit. For sure, I will be starting off at the minimum and move gradually from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...]as long as the voltage supplied to the speaker measures up to
> ~25Vpeak from an oscilloscope, the speaker can be expected to output
> sound?

Yes, you should expect sound out. With 25V peak sine wave applied, you could damage the speaker:

- from overheating its voice coil wires
- from distorting the **voice coil form**

As Neil says, 40W into a voice coil MIGHT overheat it. It might take 40W from a sine wave generator for a fraction of a second before temperature becomes excessive.

If you happen to apply a sine wave frequency at resonance, cone excursion can be very large, so that the cone mechanically whacks against the magnet - you can hear this as bad distortion. Forces are high, and the **coil winding form** can be damaged. At frequencies other than resonance, cone excursion is usually smaller. Note that resonance of an unenclosed speaker (as in your photo) differs from a speaker-in-a-box.

An 8 ohm loudspeaker likely has 8 ohm impedance at ONE frequency - at other frequencies, its impedance is complex, and greater than 8 ohms.
Your voltage calculations are common (voltage is usually easiest to measure). Seems fair, because many audio power amplifiers meant to drive loudspeakers are nearest to being described as a **voltage source** rather than a current source. That is, amplifier output resistance is less than that of a speaker.